# Polymer 1.0: Where is documentation for <iron-flex-layout>?

Tags: polymer, flexbox, polymer-1.0

Is there any documentation available for how to use Polymer 1.0 `<iron-flex-layout>` element?

Previous research:

- [Polymer web site](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-flex-layout)
- [Polymer Github](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/2f0766fcc334fee1e72e13e6a8b1de21760efdc9/iron-flex-layout.html)
- [Flexbox site](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these following links:

- [Documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) *(Recommended)*
- [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xIARqr?p=preview) *(Recommended)* *(Note to osX/Safari users: Must view in Chrome)*
  `<div class="horizontal layout">`
- [Guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details)
- [Examples](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/demo/x-app.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yikes -- I didn't realize they hadn't shimmed backward compatibility for everything.